# Mysql SELECT CASE LIKE give a NULL row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, case

I'm using the following query, but it gives a `NULL` row with the rest of results:

```
SELECT  CASE 
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%MSIE+8.0%' or csuseragent like '%Trident%' THEN 'IE'
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%Firefox%' THEN 'Firefox'
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%chrome%' THEN 'chrome'
END AS Browser ,count(*) as num
FROM logs.log
group by Browser
order by num desc

+---------+--------+
| Browser | num    |
+---------+--------+
| chrome  | 319607 |
| NULL    | 125974 |
| Firefox | 124627 |
| IE      |  56913 |
+---------+--------+
```

So how do I remove `NULL` and `125974`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause to filter out groups:

```
SELECT  CASE 
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%MSIE+8.0%' or csuseragent like '%Trident%' THEN 'IE'
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%Firefox%' THEN 'Firefox'
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%chrome%' THEN 'chrome'
END AS Browser ,count(*) as num
FROM logs.log
GROUP BY Browser
HAVING Browser IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY num DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `WHERE Browser IS NOT NULL` clause

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
SELECT  CASE 
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%MSIE+8.0%' or csuseragent like '%Trident%' THEN 'IE'
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%Firefox%' THEN 'Firefox'
WHEN csuseragent LIKE '%chrome%' THEN 'chrome'
WHEN Browser IS NOT NULL
END AS Browser ,count(*) as num
FROM logs.log

group by Browser
order by num desc
```